# PHP counting rtf file words

Tags: php

I need to count words in a rtf file. I don't know how to this. It seems using `file_get_contents()` is not reliable. And PHP cannot read it by itself. Can anybody help?

I use `file_get_contents()` and it fetches all information but is not reliable.

Comment: Why do you think it is not _reliable_ ?

Comment: I've just read somewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the link http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_the_clean_text_from_rtf.php.

Thanks

Comment: You could even paste that code from that site and credit the link below. I am saying this because if that site becomes down , your answer will also become invalid. Hope you get what am saying ;)